# I want my input to be connected to functions to be validated

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good day everyone,
I want my input to validate this formula

```
function toCelsius(f) {
  return (5/9) * (f-32);
}
```

So that anytime I change the input number, the answer changes. I tried this function, but I am not getting the required solution.

This is what I tried:

```
put=toCelsius(value);
if (isNaN(x) ) {
   text = "Input is not a number";
} else {
   text = toCelsius;
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = put;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your code work, all you have to do is to **use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and bind an event to your form**. So I just made a simple form with input and a submit button, then I will listen to the button `click` after that I will run your provided function *(with a bit modification)*.

So the final output will be something like this:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const message = document.getElementById("message");

button.addEventListener("click", toCelsius);

function toCelsius(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const inputValue = input.value;
  const toCelsiusValue = (5 / 9) * (inputValue - 32)
  
  if (isNaN(toCelsiusValue) || !inputValue) {
    message.innerHTML = "Input is not a number";
  } else {
    message.innerHTML = ""
    input.value = toCelsiusValue
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    <input type="text">
    <button>Convert</button>
  </form>
  <p id="message"></p>
</div>
```